# Order of operation with piping

Tags: r, magrittr

My question is where does the piping operator of `magrittr` package `%>%` come in the order of operations?

I have a problem simmilar to the following:

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(3),b=rnorm(3),c=rnorm(3))
df/rowSums(df)  %>%  round(.,3)
```

This results in the following non rounded figures:

> ```
>            a        b         c
> 1 -0.0121966 0.119878 0.8922125
> ```

To get the rounded figures I need to put `df/rowSums(df)` between brackets.

I experimented with the `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` and `^` and from the results I found the order of operation is as follow:

1. Exponents
2. Piping
3. Multiplication and division
4. Addition and subtraction

Is that right or there is something wrong with my understanding of the piping operator?

Comment: Don't forget that `/` is a function, so in a pipe I think it would be `rowSums(df) %>% \`/\`(df, .) %>% round(3)` because `rowSums()` is taken first, then `/`.  Or more simply, and in *magrittr* speak `divide_by(df, rowSums(df)) %>% round(3)`

Comment: `df %>% "/"(rowSums(.)) %>% round(3)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The help page you are looking for is [`?Syntax`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html).  (Don't feel bad for not being able to find this, it took me about six guesses at search keywords.)  I'm going to quote its entire operator precedence table here:

> The following unary and binary operators are defined.  They are
> listed in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.
>
> ```
> ‘:: :::’           access variables in a namespace              
> ‘$ @’              component / slot extraction                  
> ‘[ [[’             indexing                                     
> ‘^’                exponentiation (right to left)               
> ‘- +’              unary minus and plus                         
> ‘:’                sequence operator                            
> ‘%any%’            special operators (including ‘%%’ and ‘%/%’) 
> ‘* /’              multiply, divide                             
> ‘+ -’              (binary) add, subtract                       
> ‘< > <= >= == !=’  ordering and comparison                      
> ‘!’                negation                                     
> ‘&  &&’            and                                          
> ‘| ||’             or                                           
> ‘~’                as in formulae                               
> ‘-> ->>’           rightwards assignment                        
> ‘<- <<-’           assignment (right to left)                   
> ‘=’                assignment (right to left)                   
> ‘?’                help (unary and binary)
> ```

So  magrittr's pipe operators, like *all* the operators of the form `%whatever%`, do indeed have precedence greater than multiply and divide but lower than exponentiation, and this is guaranteed by the language specification.

---

I don't think the expression you showed is a good place to use `%>%` piping.  Why not just write

```
round(df/rowSums(df), 3)
```

which has the evaluation order you want, and is (IMNSHO) easier to read as well?

Comment: Yes, there are times when the pipe is nice and useful, this is not one of them.

Comment: That is very useful and yes, `round(df/rowSums(df), 3)` is better in this case.

Comment: The pipe is still more intuitive in this sense it follows the order of thought: divide by rowsums and then round.  It should come after / * + - though, imho, though not an option at this point it seems.

Comment: @jtr13 I agree. I arrived at this page with an artificial example of `100*1.23456 %>% round(2)` and `round(100*1.23456, 2)`, which one would intuitively expect to return the same value (and also after reading magrittr documentation: `x %>% f is equivalent to f(x)`). That would be in line how one normally "thinks" in terms of piping. However, the precedence rules seem to contradict this logic. @hadley ?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of Perl 6's kitchen-sink-iness, but [letting you define the precedence of user-defined operators](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/day-22-operator-overloading-revisited/) is clearly the Right Thing from an abstract language design perspective.