# How to round prop.table in r-fiddle

Tags: r

I am a newbie to r-fiddle. I am trying to round prop.tables with margins of 1 & 2 to the nearest tenth. Here's the code that I'm using. The rounding works on the 1st prop.table without a margin - but does nothing to the two tables with margins.

```
# table gives a table of counts 
table(sex, educ) 
# sending the result of table to prop.table gives joint distn 
table(sex, educ) %>% prop.table()*100 %>% round(.,1)  
# margin selects whether rows or columns sum to 1 
table(sex, educ) %>% prop.table(margin = 2)*100 %>% round(.,1) 
table(sex, educ) %>% prop.table(margin = 1)*100 %>% round(.,1)
```

The last two commands will display the information to the point of *100, then no rounding.

Comment: Suggested dupe: [Order or operation with piping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38531508/903061). The pipe has higher precedence than `*`, so `100  %>% round(1)` is completed before the multiplication.

Comment: If you really want to use pipes for multiplication, use `magrittr::multiply_by` or a lot of curly braces. Or just don't try to use pipes for literally everything.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor! Can you please show me in the code? Newbie for me - means that I don't even know what pipes are...sorry! Would the magrittr::multiply by fix my rounding issue in the last two prop.tables?

Comment: Replace `*100` with `%>% multiply_by(100)`. Make sure you have loaded `library(magrittr)`.

Comment: "*I don't even know what pipes are*". This is a pipe: `%>%`.