is.na gives unexpected result when used after magrittr pipe %>%
I'm using == to compare two character vectors, one of which contains NA elements. I then want to pipe the logical output of == to is.na using the magrittr pipe operator %>%. When I do this directly I get an unexpected result. When I bracket the == comparison with (...), or save the output of == to an object, the piping works. What am I missing about the function of either %>% or is.na? Thanks.
cvglists <- structure(
  list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), 
  names = c("x", "y", "z", NA, NA)
)
bw_use <-  list(
  x = "bigwig_nos", 
  y = "bigwig_nos", 
  z = "bigwig_nos", 
  a = "bigwig_nos", 
  b = "bigwig_nos"
)
names(cvglists) == names(bw_use)[1:length(cvglists)] %>% is.na()
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA                                   ## unexpected
(names(cvglists) == names(bw_use)[1:length(cvglists)]) %>% is.na()
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE                                   ## expected
## work around
tmp <- names(cvglists) == names(bw_use)[1:length(cvglists)]
tmp %>% is.na()
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE                                   ## expected

EDIT: I'm pretty sure the issue is my intended RHS of == is being piped to is.na, and then the ouput of is.na is being used as the RHS of == (see code below).
> names(cvglists) == (names(bw_use)[1:length(cvglists)] %>% is.na())
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA                                   ## unexpected
> (names(cvglists) == names(bw_use)[1:length(cvglists)]) %>% is.na()
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE                                   ## expected

I found these explanations:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html
Order of operation with piping

Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38531508/6851825

It's unclear what your question is. You already seemed to link to the answer. Because if operator syntax in R, a == b %>% c() is the same as a == (b %>% c()). The %>% has a higher precedence according to the Syntax page you link.

I did eventually figure out the answer to my question, after I wrote it. I didn't know what search terms to use initially and didn't find the answer until after I had an epiphany and tested the (... == ...) %>% ... solution. That led me to the question linked by @JonSpring. Hopefully, the wording of this question will help people who don't know to search for "precedence". Closing this question as a duplicate makes sense. Thanks.
